# What kind of a circuitry do I need to combine two power inputs of different voltages?

Tags: voltage, battery-charging

I have a 250Wh battery bank in my car that I charge via a 100w solar panel or a 12v car charger. The problem is there is only one charging port (a barrel connector) on the battery and I need to constantly swap the input between the solar and the 12v depending on the weather/if I'm driving etc.

I want to make a circuit that essentially combines the inputs from both the solar and the 12v, which are at different voltages (roughly 24v and 12v respectively).
Can I simply put diodes so that the current can only flow one way (ie. to the battery, and not from the solar panel to the 12v charger or vice versa), or do I also need a voltage regulator to match the voltages of the two inputs?

The portable battery has its own BMS and charging circuitry, and presumably can take any voltage between 12v and 24v as a valid input FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the charger can accept any voltage between **11V** and 24V, then you can connect all grounds (-) together, and use 2 diodes : one from each power source (car and solar) towards the battery (ie preventing any current from the battery or the other source to back-power a source that is off or lower voltage). If you need a schematics, say so, and I can add one this evening (I'm out of time to do it now).

Please note that you will have a voltage drop in the diodes. This will result :

- in a slightly lower voltage : if using the car for charging, you might not get the battery to 100% charged (but the last bit of charging provides not so much capacity, so probably no big deal). Depeding on the BMS, it might convert voltage and solve this issue, or not.
- you lose some power in the diode, so you will use a little more fuel when using the car, or a bit more time to charge with solar. As a rule of the thumb, let's say you lose 1V, so it's about 8% loss charging with the car, and 4% using 24V from solar
- the diode might heat : choose diodes rated for enough current, and add a heat sink if needed. Think about heat dissipation when mounting.
- best choose a diode with low voltage drop (a Schottky diode for example) : it reduces all the problems above. Choose one with big enough current ratings (take some decent margin)

EDIT :
adding schematics :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffulPZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NB : depending on the charger, it might not have "in-" and "out-", but just "-" : in that case, consider that the "-" pin regroup both "int -" and "out -" : you will connect all the "-" together.

For the diodes :

- for the solar panel one, I would take one rated for the short circuit current of the solar panel. 2.6A is far from being enough. The most optimistic case for a 100W panel would be that it stays at 24V, so you would have 100W/24W = 4A. In practice however, to get maximal power, the voltage of the panel usually drops, so to keep the power, the current is even more. Expect at least the double. For more precise information, we would need the datasheet of your solar panel. In case you can't get it (and short circuit current isn't written on the panel), I would recommend you use a diode rated AT LEAST 20A (less would probably be enough, but we need more data to know what is the minimum)
- for the one for the power from the car : the battery of the car can produce huge currents. So the limiting element will be the charger. Check the maximum input current of your charger, and add some safty margin (at least 50%)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah a schematics would be very helpful to avoid making a mistake! On the diode rating, my local electronics store has a shottkey diode rated for 40v at 2.6A, which puts it at 104W max. Since the panel is rated to 100W at 24V, is this enough?

Comment: No, it's far from enough, I edited my post to add more information on how to know which rating is needed

Answer (score 1):

A pair of diodes would do.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Comment: This concept can properly work with most diodes with high enough rates current. Schottky diodes may prove better due to lower forward drop and thus lower loss. "Ideal diodes" could greatly reduce losses further.

Comment: my local electronics store has a shottkey diode rated for 40v at 2.6A, which puts it at 104W max. Since the panel is rated to 100W at 24V, is this enough?

Comment: The diode current rating would depend on the charging rate. 250 Wh would translate to 250 / 12 = 20.83 Ah. Charging at 0.1C would mean a charging current of 2.1 A. A 2.6 A diode would be just okay. A 50 V 5A diode would be right. Please check whether 0.1C is okay for you (full charge will take 15 hours).

Comment: This is sometimes called power combiner, such as https://millswoodeng.com.au/documents/power_combiner_data_sheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Diodes will work, but will dissipate power. If that becomes a problem you can use an "ideal diode" circuit, which mimics diode functionality without voltage drop.

Be sure to not overload the wires carrying the power in the case where the battery bank is shorted and will draw maximum power from both inputs.